# Trying to print ints in MIPS, coming out as ASCII?

Tags: mips

Here is some relevant code. I extracted these ints from a .txt file into buffer, and then use extractInts to format them into an array (intArray). Then I use printArray to loop through it and print. The ints in intArray are stored in a .space of 80 bytes, each in their own word.
My current output:
`The array: 14385 57 14130 53 14388 13873 50 13109 13366 14393`
My expected output:
`The array: 18 9 27 5 48 16 2 53 64 98`

```
# put ints into array
extractInts:

la $s0, buffer      # $s0 points to buffer
la $s1, intArray    # $s1 points to intArray
li $t0, 0           # i = 0
li $t1, 3           # intLoop max = 3
li $t3, 4           # nextWord max = 4

    # loop to place each int within its own word boundary in intArray
    intLoop:
    beq $t0, $t1, exitLoop  # exit loop if i = end of word
    lb $t2, ($s0)           # $t2 = intArray[]
    beq $t2, '\n', nextWord # if $t2 = \n, go to nextWord
    beq $t2, '\0', exitLoop # if $t2 = \0, go to exitLoop
    sb $t2, ($s1)           # save byte in $t2 to intArray[]
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # i++
    addi $s0, $s0, 1        # increment buffer
    addi $s1, $s1, 1        # increment intArray
    j intLoop
    
        # skip to next word
        nextWord:
        sub $t4, $t3, $t0   # $t4 = 4 - i    
        add $s1, $s1, $t4   # increment intArray by $t4
        li $t0, 0           # restore i to 0        
        addi $s0, $s0, 1    # increment buffer
        j intLoop

printArray:

    li $t0, 0       # i = 0
        
    while:
        beq $t0, 80, exit       # exit if i = end of array
            
        lw $t1, intArray($t0)   # $t1 = intArray[$t0]
            
        addi $t0, $t0, 4        # move to next word in intArray
            
        # print current int
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall 
        
        # print space
        li $v0, 11 
        li $a0, 32
        syscall
        
        j while
```

Comment: Ok, so somewhere in between the input and the output it went wrong.  Identify a small input (e.g. 1 number) that goes wrong and single step through this to find the problems

Comment: The output you're getting is the expected output. You're never converting the strings in text file into numbers; all you're doing is removing whitespace and copying the characters from one piece of memory to another.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that cleared things up for me.